# How to know what server and port to select in MongoVue

Tags: mongodb, windows, installation

I am unsure about which server and port to select when trying to start up MongoVue.
FYI, MongoVue is the windows GUI for using mongodb (for those macusers who may want to answer this question).
I have a windows laptop and have already installed mongodb.

I have received a data dump with a lot of json and bson files.
The files are on my computer.

I don't know how to connect and upload all these json and bson files onto my MongoVue interface.

I am asked to fill in a server and port name. When I tried to type "localhost" for server name, it didn't work.
I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try using;

**Server: 127.0.0.1
Port: 27017**

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Install MongoDB on windows: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Copy those files to the data directory you might have configured for your MongoDB e.g C:\data\db

Once you have done the above steps, open MONGOVUE and fil in the details.

[image]